# For some odd reason, I can't run my JPA code.. "The length cannot be negative."

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans, bean-validation, payara

I got this wierd bug, when i'm trying to add an record to my database, using JPA. I've previous used the same technique to add other records in different tables.. I do not understand the error i've gotten.

```
 Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB HelpRequestBean, method: public void sessionBeans.HelpRequestBean.assignHelpRequest(transferClasses.HelpRequestDetails,int)
    Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:750)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:700)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:505)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4538)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1989)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy334.assignHelpRequest(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:173)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
    Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000032: Unable to initialize org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.initializeConstraint(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.createAndInitializeValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:547)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:487)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:451)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:403)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:78)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4314)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4291)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4233)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
        at sessionBeans.HelpRequestBean.assignHelpRequest(HelpRequestBean.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4758)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor232.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4730)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4718)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HV000021: The length cannot be negative.
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.validateParameters(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.initialize(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.SizeValidatorForCharSequence.initialize(SizeValidatorForCharSequence.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.initializeConstraint(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:245)
        ... 71 more
```

Following code:

```
@Override
    public void assignHelpRequest(HelpRequestDetails helprequest, int userID) {
        //Helpreply reply = new Helpreply(Integer.MAX_VALUE, "", "", new Date());
        Helpreply reply = new Helpreply();
        reply.setRequestID(em.find(Helprequest.class, helprequest.getRequestID()));
        reply.setUserID(em.find(Users.class, userID));
        em.persist(reply);

        Helprequest request = em.find(Helprequest.class, helprequest.getRequestID());
        request.setStatus(1);
        em.merge(request);    
    }
```

Helpreply entity class.

```
package database;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Christian
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "helpreply")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Helpreply.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM Helpreply h"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Helpreply.findByReplyID", query = "SELECT h FROM Helpreply h WHERE h.replyID = :replyID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Helpreply.findByTitle", query = "SELECT h FROM Helpreply h WHERE h.title = :title"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Helpreply.findByContent", query = "SELECT h FROM Helpreply h WHERE h.content = :content"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Helpreply.findByCreationDate", query = "SELECT h FROM Helpreply h WHERE h.creationDate = :creationDate")})
public class Helpreply implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "replyID")
    private Integer replyID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 0)
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 0)
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "creationDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date creationDate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users userID;
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestID", referencedColumnName = "requestID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Helprequest requestID;

    public Helpreply() {
    }

    public Helpreply(Integer replyID) {
        this.replyID = replyID;
    }

    public Helpreply(Integer replyID, String title, String content, Date creationDate) {
        this.replyID = replyID;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Integer getReplyID() {
        return replyID;
    }

    public void setReplyID(Integer replyID) {
        this.replyID = replyID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Users getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Users userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public Helprequest getRequestID() {
        return requestID;
    }

    public void setRequestID(Helprequest requestID) {
        this.requestID = requestID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (replyID != null ? replyID.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Helpreply)) {
            return false;
        }
        Helpreply other = (Helpreply) object;
        if ((this.replyID == null && other.replyID != null) || (this.replyID != null && !this.replyID.equals(other.replyID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "database.Helpreply[ replyID=" + replyID + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems there is a Bean Validation annotation in the `Helpreply` class which incorrectly specifies that a length of a string value should be less than zero. Please post the code for `Helpreply` to your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I added my entity class now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments I got.

What i needed to get rid of the errors was to remove

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 0)
```

From my entity class. This was the the reason for the error I got. I think it explain it self, why it didn't work :-)